# C# Azure functions translator

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, translators

I began to study the azure function

An interesting question is how to implement the function of translating text into any language

I searched for books and googled, and watched the training videos on YouTube, but could not realize it

Also in the future, the process of testing functions is interesting.
For example, how to send a million requests and track errors

Can anyone tell me how to implement this function-translator? Or someone has similar.

Thanks

Comment: it is very unclear, what you are actually asking. please share relevant code that shows what you have tried so far and where you are stuck

Comment: No we can't because a) that sounds like a huge job, far too much for an SO question (translation itself is no simple task, it's a job for AI really, not a little function) and b) you haven't given us anything beyond the most basic of requirements anyway. It's also unclear what "could not realize it" actually means. Presumably you got stuck at some particular stage...maybe you would like help with that specific thing? If so, please tell us more about that, instead.

Comment: Mark, as others have pointed out, this isn't the type of question that Stack Overflow is meant for. If you have a **very** specific coding problem, then we can help you.  Example: "Why am I getting this error message?".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ADyson "any" language it was meant one language. for example german to EN

and for testing translate "hello world"
not the google translator and AI as you write

Comment: @MarkKovak then you should have made it clear what the intention was. We are not mind readers! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cognitive Services (Text API) which will perform the translations for you.

Here's a sample about how to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-translate?pivots=programming-language-csharp

Another good example in here: https://anthonychu.ca/post/realtime-captioning-translation-cognitive-services-signalr-azure-functions/ (this one with Azure Functions)

and more info about the supported languages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/language-support